# Hive describe extended table return json

Tags: sql, hive

Is there any way to run "describe extended table" in Hive and have the results returned in `JSON`, `XML`, or some easily parsed format? Or is there an existing parse in `Java` that can parse this type of format?

> Table(tableName:test3, dbName:testdatabase, owner:johnsmith, createTime:1481135997, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:a, type:string, comment:""a,m)], location:hdfs://testcluster/apps/hive/warehouse/testdatabase/test3, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{totalSize=0, numRows=0, rawDataSize=0, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE={"BASIC_STATS":"true"}, numFiles=0, transient_lastDdlTime=1481135997}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)

Comment: For humans, SHOW CREATE TABLE is way more readable *(IMHHO - in my humble human opinion)*

Comment: And if you really want to access the raw information in Java, try the Metastore API -- poorly documented but taps into the real thing http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/package-summary.html *(adjust to the actual Hive version you are using)*

Comment: Another option is to access the Metastore (!) that is also SQL... But [it is possible with beeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57401967/287948)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DESCRIBE FORMATTED my_table;` is more friendly
not json or xml.. but more readable than `DESCRIBE EXTENDED my_table;`

Comment: It is not structured data, **is not friendly for programemers, data filters, etc.**. Need JSON or XML, like in any other good SGDB (like PostgreSQL or Oracle).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [`hive.ddl.output.format`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2822) to format output

```
set hive.ddl.output.format=json;
desc extended table;
```

Comment: Not works, *"Error: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify hive.ddl.output.format at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=42000,code=1)"*

Comment: which hive version?  [hive config source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java) can find this config, 
maybe your hive server can't change some params when runtime, you can check your hive config this settings: `set hive.conf.restricted.list;` [hive config details](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

Comment: Hi Saboloh, thanks the clues! I am using Hive *v1.2*... Is difficult to change corporative cluster... My local `hive.conf.restricted.list` is *hive.security.authenticator.manager, hive.security.authorization.manager, hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager, hive.security.metastore.authenticator.manager, hive.users.in.admin.role,hive.server2.xsrf.filter.enabled, hive.security.authorization.enabled*