# How to access Metastore from beeline?

Tags: hive, beeline

I need to do some SQL queries (as [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/208790/how-to-query-tablecolumn-comments-in-hive-metastor.html)) directly from Metasore. 
PS: the commands SHOW/DESCRIBE are *not* enough.

How to enable access from it as database, or what the database name of Metastore? ... In nowadays (2019) it is possible?

---

NOTES

- What is **Metastore**? 
  For me is a very important element of the Hive architecture, final  user need some access to it... *"All Hive implementation need a metastore service, where it stores metadata. It is implemented using tables in relational database. By default, Hive uses built-in Derby SQL server"*, [1](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Hive-Metastore). 
  Of course, you need **in your context** a *"standard" Metastore*. On my corporation's Hadoop cluster  we are planning to standardize Metastore (local and long term standard), perhaps PostgreSQL and also an ([PostgREST API](http://postgrest.org) for external consume of some SQL-Views from it).
- The SQL definitions (table names, etc.) will be stable and Metastore queries will be reliable when Metastore is a long-term local standard.
- The Metastore  it is closely connected to Hive, where it is a Java API, but Metastore is also a standard RDBMS and offers standard connection (by SQL) for the external universe. 
  PS: my interest on Metastore is in this external context.

Comment: Metastore is a Java service with a Java API. That's the "proper" way to interact with it.

Comment: Metastore(s) use a RDBMS as back-end, the connection params are either in `hive-metastore.xml` or _(legacy)_ in `hive-site.xml` used by Metastore service(s). You may try to query that one, but the model is not really documented, evolves, and has nuances for each RDBMS dialect supported.

Comment: ...and in the future the back-end might be HBase and good luck for querying that one.

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, thanks for your comments. I edited with some notes... It make sense?  PS: I not see Metastore as "Java API", because RDBMS connections are universal (any language and standard SQL access).

Comment: _(deep sigh)_ the Metastore **service** is a **Java application**; client/server communication uses Thrift message protocol. It has a **back-end** to persist information, which is currently a relational database, but might use HBase in the future.

Comment: If you run a toy Hadoop cluster, with no proper Metastore service, then HiveServer2 (or Spark) will bootstrap an "embedded" Metastore service, with an "embedded" Derby database. But that's for test purposes only -- no real persistence, no sharing of table definitions between tools.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880050/get-table-properties-out-of-hive-using-java-api

Answer (score 0):

### Spark-shell solution

Spark access Metastore under the hood, it have a [first class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) metadata method, that returns a dataframe, the `schema` property, that expose names, types, etc. and offers `getComment` method.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57857021/287948